# Retrieve Contact photo imported from Linkedin via REST API

Tags: soql, rest-api

I have connected my social network Linkedin  profile on Salesforce-Contacts.

I have updated the photos of few contacts and I want to get that photos via Salesforce REST API. is it possible?

I am not finding any field specifying that photo in fieldlist of standard Contact Object.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing Contact's Social information via API is not yet supported - there is already a feature request https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bOFxAAM